# How does KVL work in this circuit?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I am working through my textbook and came across a KVL scenario that I don't understand. In the problem we were tasked to find the current \$i_x\$ with node voltages. I can follow the solution that is laid out in the text except for one part. A portion of the solution involves writing a KVL for the portion of the circuit located in the bottom right box. The circuit is displayed below:

[image]

The KVL that the text came up with is shown below along with the text:
[image]

What I don't understand is that they wrote a KVL loop and they seemed to have ignored the 20 V source. How is it that the 20 V source voltage is not part of the KVL equation if it's a part of the KVL loop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they actually identified, or needed, a loop to write that equation. The equation in question can be written by inspection looking at the value of the source and the names of the nodes at each end.

Answer (score 1):

KVL doesn't have to be a completed "loop." It can just be *"from point **A** to point **B**"*, if you prefer. Often, in fact, it starts from a voltage source and ends at ground. Or goes from one voltage source to another one. What counts is whether or not what you write actually helps you, or not.

For example, here's your schematic, re-drawn but otherwise no different:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYGGEC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's perfectly valid KVL to write, assuming the current directions are positive when "downward":

$$20\:\text{V}-I_{R_3}\cdot R_3-I_{R_1}\cdot R_1=0\:\text{V}$$

It may or may not be helpful. But at least it's valid.

The \$20\:\text{V}\$ source doesn't have to be part of the KVL if the KVL itself isn't some entire loop you are imagining, but instead only going *from **A** to **B***. Again, whether or not that's helpful remains to be seen. But you haven't disclosed their solution, either. So all I can say is that what they wrote is valid. It's not a loop. But it is valid, just the same.